# Picture and Table centered alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, vertical-alignment

this looks messy right now.
How can i achieve the following:

Caption of picture is centered under the picture and caption of table is centered under the table.
Both captions are on the same vertical height.
The table is centered vertically centered to the height of the picture.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,ngerman,reqno,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}     % ams stuff should be before font loading
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % should be after font loading
\usepackage{fixltx2e,babel}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}    % bibtex package
%\usepackage{typearea}           % custom type area
%   \areaset[0mm]{135mm}{210mm}  % typearea configuration
%   \topmargin5mm                % typearea configuration
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}


      \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.40\textwidth}
        \centering
       \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=Züge$\text{[}\#\text{]}$,
            ylabel=Zeit$\text{[}s\text{]}$,
            axis y line=center,
            grid=both,
            axis x line=center,
            ymax=2000,
            symbolic x coords = {10, 20, 50, 100, 200,500,1000,2000}]

        \addplot[color=red,mark=*,style=dashed] coordinates {
            (10,25)
            (20,12)
            (50,33)
            (100,1800)
            (200,1800)
            (500,1800)
            (1000,509)
            (2000,1514)
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionof{figure}{A table beside a figure}
      \end{minipage}
      \hfill
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.40\textwidth}
        \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|c|c} 
       Züge[\#] & Zeit[s] & Lücke[\%]\\ \hline \hline 
       10 & 25 & 0.00 \\ 
       20 & 12 & 0.00 \\
       50  & 333 & 0.00 \\
       100 & 1800 & 1.92 \\ 
       200 & 1800 & 1.08 \\
       500 & 1800 & 21.37 \\
       1000 & 509 & 0.00\\ 
       2000 & 1514 & 0.00 \\ \hline 
    \end{tabularx}
          \captionof{table}{A table beside a figure}
        \end{minipage}
      \end{minipage}
      \end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: the mwe is now here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with the `floatrow` package. I adjusted the margins, with the geometry package, but you may as well adjust table or figure. In addition, I loaded `siunitx` to have a proper alignment of numbers in their columns and `makecell` to have a better vertical spacing between rows and use thicker horizontal rule at the bottom of the table (`booktabs` doesn't work with vertical rules):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,ngerman,reqno,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm} % ams stuff should be before font loading
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % should be after font loading
\usepackage{fixltx2e,babel}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{hhline, array, makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\makegapedcells
\usepackage[showframe, margin = 25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{I}{S[table-format=4.0]}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}\CenterFloatBoxes
  \begin{floatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    { \caption{A figure beside a table}\label{figuretab}}
    { \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          xlabel=Züge$\text{[}\#\text{]}$,
          ylabel=Zeit$\text{[}s\text{]}$,
          axis y line=center,
          grid=both,
          axis x line=center,
          ymax=2000,
        symbolic x coords = {10, 20, 50, 100, 200,500,1000,2000}]

        \addplot[color=red,mark=*,style=dashed] coordinates {
          (10,25)
          (20,12)
          (50,33)
          (100,1800)
          (200,1800)
          (500,1800)
          (1000,509)
          (2000,1514)
        };
      \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \ffigbox[1.08\FBwidth][1.25\FBheight]{\captionof{table}{A table beside a figure}\label{tablefig}}
    {\begin{tabular}{@{}I|I|S[table-format = 2.2]@{}}
      {Züge\,[\#]} & {Zeit\,[s]} &{ Lücke\,[\%]} \\
      \hhline{ >{\arrayrulewidth = 2pt}:=:=:=:}
      10 & 25 & 0.00 \\
      20 & 12 & 0.00 \\
      50 & 333 & 0.00 \\
      100 & 1800 & 1.92 \\
      200 & 1800 & 1.08 \\
      500 & 1800 & 21.37 \\
      1000 & 509 & 0.00\\
      2000 & 1514 & 0.00 \\
      \Xhline{0.8pt}
      \end{tabular}}%
  \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you are using the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package, use `{Zeit\,[\si{\s}]} & {Lücke\,[\si{\percent}]}` instead of `{Zeit\,[s]} &{ Lücke\,[\%]}`. (The same with the y-axis label.)

Answer (score 3):

Might this be what you seek?  You needed a `\noindent`, and the figure needed a little shrinking to fit in the margins.  Also, I used stacks to both align the captions and dial in the vertical offset of the table to achieve a centered look.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,ngerman,reqno,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}     % ams stuff should be before font loading
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % should be after font loading
\usepackage{fixltx2e,babel}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}    % bibtex package
%\usepackage{typearea}           % custom type area
%   \areaset[0mm]{135mm}{210mm}  % typearea configuration
%   \topmargin5mm                % typearea configuration
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{stackengine,lipsum}
\newsavebox\tmpbox
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\par\bigskip
      \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
        \centering
       \sbox{\tmpbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=Züge$\text{[}\#\text{]}$,
            ylabel=Zeit$\text{[}s\text{]}$,
            axis y line=center,
            grid=both,
            axis x line=center,
            ymax=2000,
            symbolic x coords = {10, 20, 50, 100, 200,500,1000,2000}]

        \addplot[color=red,mark=*,style=dashed] coordinates {
            (10,25)
            (20,12)
            (50,33)
            (100,1800)
            (200,1800)
            (500,1800)
            (1000,509)
            (2000,1514)
        };
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}}
      \setbox0=\vbox{\captionof{figure}{A table beside a figure}}
      \stackon{\box0}{\scalebox{.8}{\usebox{\tmpbox}}}
      \end{minipage}  
      \hfill
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.40\textwidth}
        \centering
      \sbox{\tmpbox}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|c|c} 
       Züge[\#] & Zeit[s] & Lücke[\%]\\ \hline \hline 
       10 & 25 & 0.00 \\ 
       20 & 12 & 0.00 \\
       50  & 333 & 0.00 \\
       100 & 1800 & 1.92 \\ 
       200 & 1800 & 1.08 \\
       500 & 1800 & 21.37 \\
       1000 & 509 & 0.00\\ 
       2000 & 1514 & 0.00 \\ \hline 
      \end{tabularx}}
      \setbox0=\vbox{\captionof{table}{A table beside a figure}}
      \stackon[17pt]{\box0}{\usebox{\tmpbox}}
        \end{minipage}
      \end{minipage}\par
\medskip
\lipsum[2]
      \end{document}
```

[image]